# How to include an Iframe within a Vaadin App?

Tags: gwt, widget, vaadin

I would like to include an Iframe within my Vaadin App, how do I proceed implementing this? My initial idea was to wrap the GWT Frame widget, using the approach as [described in the Book of Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.integration.html). Is this at all possible, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I didn't read the manual (Book of Vaadin) good enough. I found the answer to my question in section [5.15.3 Browser Frames](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html). Ups.

Comment: For Vaadin seven its https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html#components.embedded.browserframe